# A drop down select that's actually a text input box, like on Google Calendar?

Tags: javascript, html, google-calendar-api

I noticed Google calendar uses this instead of <select>

```
<input class="text dr-time" id=":3r-st" size="7" title="From time" tabindex="0" dir="ltr" />
```

It let's the user type the time instead of selecting an option from the drop down list. Is there a plugin or nice widget someone wrote that does the same thing?

Comment: Check out http://www.jqueryui.com

Comment: Tool recommendation questions are off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at one of these JQuery plugins:

- http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/
- http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/
- http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

A more lightweight approach might be, assuming you only have text and not dates, using the `data-list` attribute:

```
<div>Choose a browser from this list:</div>
<input list="browsers" />
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

I copied the above code from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Chosen is something for you. It's a JavaScript SELECT replacement, which adds multiple new opportunities:

http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/